# Docker image running

Tags: docker, containers

He everyone,

I am running a docker image centos:6 which does not have anything in it. Whenever I run docker run centos:6 it runs and when I run docker ps it does not show as it is running.When I do "docker ps -a" it shows as exited. I am looking to make it permanent instead of exited.  I am assuming it has executed and finished the process. Is there any command, or directive I can include inside the docker file that can keep the docker image running and show when I run docker ps? Or am I misunderstanding something? It supposed to show that it is running in the background though

Thank you

Comment: You could use `docker ps -a` to view all containers including the stopped ones. Could you show the command to run your container?

Comment: so I run docker run centos:6 followed by docker ps -a. The status is (exited). Is there anyway I can do some changes to dockerfile that keeps container running? instead of exited status. -d option did not really help. I am using UCP and DTR images they show running

Comment: Please read the [official Docker tutorial on building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/).  A bare OS container with nothing installed in it isn’t that useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the container keep on running you can start it as a daemon like:

```
docker run -d centos:6
```

If you want to run it interactive, so you are inside the os you can run:

```
docker run -it centos:6 /bin/bash
```

Instead of bash you could place any shell which is installed and you prefer to use.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the image you're using, you need to specify a command and the `-d` and `-it` flags you daemonise it.

Example:

```
docker run -d -it centos:6 /bin/bash
```

You'll get an output with a container id like so:

```
31b02d787a8850a7eda3bd0ef91989b26ac02c5694a8626344369cfc093a05ad
```

You can then inspect the running container and get it's status:

```
docker inspect 31b02d787a8850a7eda3bd0ef91989b26ac02c5694a8626344369cfc093a05ad | jq '.[].State.Status'
"running"
```

And enter the container:

```
docker exec -it 31b02d787a8850a7eda3bd0ef91989b26ac02c5694a8626344369cfc093a05ad /bin/sh
#
```